# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: '1.id'

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, hql

I get this error but i can't figure out reason ? can anyone help me plz;

### File : AnnonceDao.java

```
public List<AnnonceColocation> listeAnnonceColocation( UserEntity idUser ) {
    Query query = getEntityManger()
            .createQuery(
                    "from AnnonceColocation, Annonce where AnnonceColocation.id = Annonce.id and Annonce.annonceUser= :idUser" )
            .setParameter( "idUser", idUser );
    List<AnnonceColocation> annonceColocation = (List) query.getResultList();
    return annonceColocation;
}
```

### File: Annonce.java

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "annonce" )
@Inheritance( strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED )
public class Annonce extends BaseEntity {

// attribut
// getter&setter

  }
```

### File: AnnonceColocation.java

```
    @Entity
    @Table( name = "annonceColocation" )
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn( name = "ID" )
    public class AnnonceColocation extends Annonce {

          // attribut 
          // getter/setter
     }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assign aliases to every entity, and use these aliases in the query:

```
from AnnonceColocation ac, Annonce a where ac.id = a.id and a.annonceUser= :idUser
```

Also, this query shows that you're using IDs of other entities instead of using associations between entities. This will make lots of queries impossible to express, and will prevent you from navigating into the entity graph easily. Read the chapter about associations in the documentation, and use them.

Comment: @user3356300 don't thank only verbally, but rather upvote and mark the answer as accepted if it helped.